# Office 365 API + Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, office365

Struggling to work something out when using Angular to connect to the Office 365 API.

I am writing a back end application to extract email attachments from a specific user mailbox and then upload the attachment into a third party tool.

This works perfectly and I am having no problems with this, however at the moment, it requires the user to keep a browser open on the site to allow this to work as the user is required to login to create the OAuth token.

I want to automate this process by storing the OAuth token from an initial login and I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

I am assuming the following would need to be changed but I am not sure to what:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'home',
            requireADLogin: true
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

Let me know what else you may need to know

Comment: I'm confused.  Store the token to be used when?  The token has some expiration time so its not like it will be usable for very long.  Do you want this process to run only when initiated by a user action in an app or unattended on some timeline?

Comment: @boburob I think you will have to give a little bit more than just the route configuration.  Giving you any advice at this point would not make sense because I have no idea how your app is even supposed to be constructed.

Comment: Okay sorry if I did not make this clear enough. The tool is designed to connect to office 365 api and pull attachments from a users inbox and upload them into another location. This works perfectly, however it requires you to keep the browser window open and to initiate the login. What I want to be able to achieve is to store the credentials of the user so that a login is not required and the site can be polled using a scheduled task to grab the latest attachments. From what I have read, you do not store credentials but rather store the token but I cannot see how.